# Pagination in vue Js

Tags: vue.js

When I add and I'm on page 2, for example, it loads a page and goes back to the first page. How can I prevent myself from being moved to the first page after the creation process?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you tried ? Can you please show some code ?

Comment: <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>

Comment: <paginate
             
                :page-link-class="'page-link'"
                :page-count="classroomSummaryLength"
                :page-range="3"
                :margin-pages="2"
                :click-handler="clickCallback"
                :prev-text="$t(prevBtn)"
                :next-text="$t(nextBtn)"
                :container-class="'pagination'"
                :page-class="'page-item'"
                :prev-class="'page-link'"
                :next-class="'page-link'"
                @click="setPageNumber()"
            >

Comment: clickCallback(pageNum) {
            let num = pageNum;
            this.currentPage = num;
            this.getSchoolTeacherClassroomsSummary(num);
        },
        setPageNumber() {
            this.clickCallback(1);
            let vm = this;
            vm.reset = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                vm.reset = true;
            }, 1000);
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getSchoolTeacherClassroomsSummary();
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getSchoolTeacherClassroomsSummary(1);
    },

Comment: Please add this code in the post instead of comments.